# issue with eleventy nunjucks exporting template code

Tags: nunjucks, eleventy

any ideas why my configuration is exporting njk code instead of content?

```
<body class="font-sans" id="top" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">

  {{ content | safe }}

  <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>

  { % include 'footer.njk' % }

</body>
```

[image]

Comment: `{ %` => `{%`: `{% include 'footer.njk' %}`

Answer (score 0):

You've got too many spaces in there.

Change

```
{ % include 'footer.njk' % }
```

to

```
{% include 'footer.njk' %}
```